# How to divide complex string (regex) in child-elements in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, multidimensional-array

I have a given string (in form of a regular expression) and need to divide it into its elements and maintain the given structure. I tried almost every str-related search and couldn't find any answer, so I hope you can help.

Example: 
`$structStr = '(((a*, b?, c?)|b|(d,e)),(f,g)+)*'`

The elements in between need to be separated in an array plus the given information +,*,?.

My ideas:

- divide it with explode/multiexplode by ',' or '|': does not work, because the explode will not check the brackets --> all child elements would be on the same level
- search for first and last bracket & divide: does not work because the last bracket must not be the closing bracket of the first, the closing can happen in between (see example) AND i will loose the additional information +,*,?.

Example for a result (as I imagine it, hope it is correct, the result is types by hand to give you an idea):

```
Array
(
    [structure] => Array
        (
    [0] => Array
        ( 
            [0]=> Array
                ( 
                    [a] => Array 
                        (
                            [count] => star
                            [content]=> xyz
                        )
                    [b] => Array 
                        (
                            [count] => optional
                            [content]=> xyz
                        )
                    [c] => Array 
                        (
                            [count] => optional
                            [content]=> xyz
                        )
                    [type] => AND       
            [1]=> Array
                ( 
                    [b] => Array 
                        (
                            [count] => none
                            [content]=> xyz
                        ) 
            [2]=> Array
                ( 
                    [d] => Array 
                        (
                            [count] => none
                            [content]=> xyz
                        )
                    [e] => Array 
                        (
                            [count] => none
                            [content]=> xyz
                        )   
                    [type] => AND
                )   
            [type] => OR     
    [1] => Array
        ( 
            [f]=> Array
                (
                    [count] => none
                    [content]=> xyz
                )       
            [g] => Array 
                (
                    [count] => none
                    [content]=> xyz
                )
            [type] => AND
            [count] => plus     
        )
    [count] = star
    )
)
```

Note: the content is not given in the regex, but i will need it as well, ignore it for now.

Comment: By what do you want to separate the regex? Did you try to use a regex itself? You would need to escape the string first

Comment: I don't really now how to divide the string without loosing information. If I extract the string first, how will i know about the additional information or the structure of the element?

Comment: If you use regex, you can define matchgdoups with paranthesies

Comment: You cannot, as the strings you are trying to parse don't conform a regular language. You need a parser for the grammar you are constructing, which is context free, as it allows nesting of subexpressions inside another expressions. A regular expression is only capable of parsing regular languages, which are simpler than context free grammars.  The syntax of a regular expression is not regular, but defined by a context free grammar.